# Can't find nix-env or nix-build on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, nix, plutus

I can't find nix-env, nix-build, nix-shell etc. on MacOS Catalina.

I installed with:

```
sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

and was able to run them yesterday. I restarted my computer and can no longer find them. `find / -name nix-env | grep nix-env` shows nothing.

I tried installing again with the same command (`sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume`) but this time it exists immediately with 0 status code.

I suspect I need to do something to mount a virtual drive.

Comment: Did you check https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation? Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: Thanks @RobertHensing, I followed those instructions, which say to do `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume` (as I wrote in the question)

Comment: For later travelers, many of the details here changed with the Nov 1, 2021 release of Nix 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Disk Utility UI to remove the nix volume (`sudo rm -rf /nix` won't work).

Then run the script again and cross fingers your fingers this time: `sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume`

Comment: update: I restarted my computer again and `nix-env` is again gone. It seems like the solution is to reinstall every time I restart.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [Notes on the recommended approach](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation-recommended-notes).

It looks like the volume is not mounted (check `/etc/fstab` state with `vifs` as described in documentation).

Comment: doesn't work: `vifs: editing error`. If `cat /etc/fstab`, I see `LABEL=Nix\040Store /nix apfs rw,nobrowse` -  exactly what the docs say should be there. But `nix-env` is still not available.

Comment: Then your `/etc/fstab` looks good. Did you follow all the steps from this section? `apfs.util` and `diskutil` commands too? And which shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While Nix (amongst others) installs with `bash` newer MacOS do use `zsh` instead of `bash`.

So you need to update your `.zshrc` to source this command from bash, too.

In your terminal start editing with:

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

and add:

```
source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
```

Reload and test with

```
source ~/.zshrc; nix --version
```

Comment: Sourcing bashrc from zshrc sounds like it could have unintended consequences: Bash and ZShell are different languages, after all. Zsh is not a strict superset of Bash, for example the same glob expansion syntax means something different in the two languages.

Comment: It's a very bad idea. There's really only one line you need to add to `.zshrc` anyway, something like `. ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`. Any other problems would be related to making sure the Nix store file system is properly mounted, which isn't something you will be doing from your shell configuration.

Comment: Acknowledged and updated. Thx guys

Comment: I can't find ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh